# When is it "acceptable" to use ViewBag/ViewData in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I realize that the best practice is to use strongly typed Views and pass in all needed data in a ViewModel, but I am curious if there are situations where it is actually considered "best practice" to pass data in the ViewBag/ViewData.

In what scenarios is the ViewBag/ViewData preferred for passing data to a view?

**update**

It's great to hear the various uses everyone has come up with for ViewBag/ViewData. We may never arrive at a "best practice" but it will be great to see the different solutions people have come up with that rely on the ViewBag/ViewData.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use them rarely, for bits of information that are totally unrelated to the model or view model that I'm passing to the view, again, most of the times I use a view model

Comment: The only scenario I can see when you'd have information that doesn't belong in the ViewModel is if you're passing information to the Layout of your View. For this scenario, I like the usage of a base ViewModel, inherited by the ViewModels belonging to all Views that use a particular Layout.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use some DTO instead of using viewbag. Using DTO make you strong type your viewdata.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would you use this method, in addtion to, or in place of strongly typing the view? And why not just strongly type the view to the DTO(or a viewmodel derived from it)?

Comment: This is what i do i strongly type my view, with DTOs. I try to avoid using viewbag. But in some case like errors you can pass them to the viewbag

Answer (score 2):

I typically will use a strongly typed view for displaying any content but will often set `ViewBag.Member` to the currently logged in member so that it can be used in the main Layout in addition to the specific view.

I have an attribute called `PopulateMemberContext` which populates `ViewBag.Member` and I add that attribute to my base controller so that every view will always have the necessary data.

"Right" or "Wrong" I don't know - but it works wonderfully.

Comment: That's what the User.Identity property is for - This will work as long as your custom authentication mechanism is an implementation of MembershipProvider.

Answer (score 1):

i can't say about best practice but i mostly use it when using Editor Templates. e.g if i want to display a dropdown list for editing certain field i make following editor template

```
<%:Html.DropDownList("GetIDHere", new SelectList((IEnumerable<someModel>)ViewData["xyz"]),"select Author")%>
```

Then you put UIHint attribute on BookID field of your model for instance

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookID{get;set;}
    [UIHint("mytemplate")]
    public int AuthorID{get;set;}
}
```

in such cases, i assume, its particularly fine and clean to use ViewData. this is the way Telerik asp.net mvc projects have coded in their demo projects [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc)

Comment: There's an argument to be made here for instead using a ViewModel, with a `Book` property and a `IEnumerable<someModel>` property, giving you strong typing.