# query IEnumerable array and select all x.profilenames

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ok so this is maybe very simple but I just can not see where I am going wrong so any help is grateful

I have a model of this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectedProfiels> profiles { get; set; }
public class SelectedProfiels
{
    public int Identifer { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
}
```

and then I am trying to read from this

i am then building an array called `selectedProfiles`,

I then have this code

```
 var pro = from s in selectedProfiles select s;
```

What im wanting to do is find all the `ProfileName`'s and assigned them there on `ViewBag.[i]` or just there own string variable

I have a model collection like this

```
var userd = new User()
            {
                ID = i.FirstOrDefault(),
                Type = t.FirstOrDefault(),                
                AuthorityLevel = a.FirstOrDefault(),
                Language = l.FirstOrDefault(),               
                Profiles = pro,               

            };


public IEnumerable<SelectedProfiels> profiles { get; set; }

public class SelectedProfiels
{
    public int Identifer { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
}
```

I then pass userd to a new page:

```
return RedirectToAction("test", "Account", userd);

 public ActionResult test (Userm)
        {
            ViewBag.d = m.profiles;

            return View();
        }
```

any help please

Comment: Reference the `s.ProfileName` property in your `select`

Comment: Just a word to the wise, please [don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766062/is-using-viewbag-in-mvc-bad) [assign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637958/when-is-it-acceptable-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-in-asp-net-mvc) [things](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328083/heavy-use-of-viewbag) to the [ViewBag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262034/mvc-viewbag-best-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, given your linq query:

```
 var pro = from s in 
           selectedProfiles 
           select s;
```

You can use `Linq` to generate an `IEnumerable` from `pro`, like:

```
var selectedProfiles = pro.Select(p => p.ProfileName).ToList();
```

Then, you can use `selectedProfiles` to populate the array you desire:

```
string[] newStrings = selectedProfiles.ToArray();
```

Comment: I understand what you have put here full but I get cannot implicitly convert 'generic list<string> to IEnumerable<User.SelectedProfiles>

Comment: Since you're only interested in the `ProfileName`, did you try to just make `profiles` be `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: I have added extra code as to how the collection is built

Comment: this 'string[] newStrings = selectedProfiles.ToArray();' works outside of the 'var used = new user()' if say i try 'Profiles  = selectedProfiles.ToArray();'

Comment: I don't see how `User` is involved with this at all. Your question was very explicit, how to get the `ProfileName` values from an `IEnumberable` into an array..This is the code that does it. If something else doesn't work then that's another question.

Comment: yes but im want to pass back userd to to the return method without the profiles being within this passing them in to a need array is ok but it needs to be within userd

Comment: It sounds like you need to add a property on your ViewModel for the array (or another List)

Comment: I think I am finally getting there :)

Comment: Good! I'm glad to hear it. I hope you do get it.

Comment: I am thanks a lot closer to doing what I want it to do now so big thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
select s
```

Just use

```
select s.ProfileName
```

Comment: yes but when you trying to assign that to a string you get cannon implicitly convert type IEnumerable generic string to IEnumerable selectedprofiles

Comment: @Mich Can you show us exactly what it is you're trying to do with the IEnumerable<ProfileName>?

Comment: the result is an IEnumerable<string>, that's what the OP wanted, or not?

Comment: I think he wants to pass the `ProfileName` for each item in the `IEnumerable` into an array.. (from `pro`)

Comment: @MarkC. iv added the other c# im trying to use